# Restoring my custom listview and data after calling onDestroy(), then onCreate() in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity, android-adapter, custom-adapter

I have a an app with an IM style page, the text is displayed using a custom listview

[image]

When I leave the activity and come back I want to still have the listview with all my data in it. SO far I have tried saving the contents of my arraylist using onSavedInstance and onRestoredInstance then setting the adapter again in onRestoredInstance but that doesn't work.

Here is my code for my activity:

```
private ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> messageList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> timeList = new ArrayList<String>();

    Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chat_send);
    EditText send = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    ListView chat_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chat_list);
    MyCustomArrayAdapter myArrayAdapter = new MyCustomArrayAdapter(this, messageList, nameList,
            timeList, receiverName, senderName, language_chosen);

    chat_list.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);       

    send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String new_text = edit_text.getText().toString();
            String sys_time = new Time(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .toString();
            timeList.add(sys_time);
            messageList.add(new_text);
            nameList.add(username);
            myArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            chat_list.setSelection(chat_list.getChildCount()-1);
        }
    });
```

And here is the code for my Adapter

```
public MyCustomArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> planetList,
        ArrayList<String> NameList, ArrayList<String> TimeList,
        String receiver, String sender, String language) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_chat_layout, planetList);
    this.context = context;
    messageList = planetList;
    nameList = NameList;
    timeList = TimeList;
    receiverName = receiver;
    senderName = sender;
    language_chosen = language;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    holder = new ViewHolder();

    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_chat_layout, parent, false);
    holder.chat_name = (TextView) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.custom_chat_name);
    holder.chat_time = (TextView) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.custom_chat_timestamp);
    holder.chat_text = (TextView) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.custom_chat_text);


    holder.chat_name.setText(nameList.get(position));
    holder.chat_time.setText(timeList.get(position));
    holder.chat_text.setText(messageList.get(position));

    return rowView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView chat_name;
    TextView chat_time;
    TextView chat_text;
    RelativeLayout relative;
    RelativeLayout relative1;
}
```

Comment: Think your missing some of your code though, but i think you just forget to save your data. it's called sharedpreferences, when its small data amount like what you are using.

Comment: I did save my arraylists using onSavedInstance but that didn't do anything. Can I use the preferences function to saved data without actually using sharedpreferences?

Comment: `onSavedInstance` state is not for saving persistent data. It is not guaranteed to be called (and in fact, neither is `onDestroy`). This is why you should instead save/load the data in `onPause` and `onResume`. You really need to save this data to persistent data storage and then reload it from the data store when you need it. There is no way from preventing the `Activity` from being destroyed... and once it is destroyed this data will be lost.

Comment: I've retagged the question... make sure you use `android-activity` instead of `activity` (and same with `android-listview` and `android-adapter`, etc.) in the future :). It will get your question more attention from SO users that follow the Android tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save the data in `onPause` and re-populate the adapter in `onResume`. Things like instant messages should be saved to persistent data storage (for example, an SQLite database), and then loaded with a `CursorAdapter`. A lot of the details of maintaining the data load across the `Activity` lifecycle can be abstracted out by making use of the `LoaderManager` and loading the data with a `CursorLoader` instead.

It also sounds like you want to have a `Service` running in the background that can receive messages and save instant messages to the data store even when the `Activity` isn't in focus.

Comment: yes I've set the service up it works well I just need to have the listview restored when i leave the activity and come back in. I'll give it a go now

Comment: Again, it really would make more sense to save this data to an SQLite database or something like that. What if the user turns off the phone? When he turns it back on, there's no way of recovering that data unless you have saved it to the disk somehow... there is no way to save information in memory w/o doing so.

Comment: That sounds alot better using the Androids databse

Answer (score 0):

in:
onPause(){
open sharedpreferences, save your lists.
}

in:
onResume(){
open sharedpreferences, restore your lists, setdata changed
}

Comment: I don't get it I'm not using preferences, what about onDestroy and onCreate

Answer (score 0):

[onSaveInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) is only used at the time your app is running. After your app stopped, all data in bundle will be released.

You should use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).